# click to download Jquery HTML dynamic page to PDF in asp.net core

Tags: html, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-core, pdf

I have a page that is dynamically populated with AJAX once the page is loaded in asp.net core. 
I have to use AJAX because I am populating the page from different sources using id parameter to get value and the page is populated. The HTML pages are working fine and the data are properly displayed.

So I tried using Rotativa base on this [tutorial](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/creating-pdf-in-asp-net-core-mvc-using-rotativa-aspnetcore/), I was able to get the pdf working but the PDF is empty because the page has not loaded before the PDF is generated.

The idea now is that if I could have a button on the page to convert the page to pdf and users can download.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

> The idea now is that if I could have a button on the page to convert the page to pdf and users can download.
>   Is there a way to achieve this?

You can use PDF.Core package to implement it, you can find it in Nuget.

Below is a working demo:

**View:**

```
<h1>Test</h1>

<input id="download" type="button" value="download" />

<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#download").on("click", function () {
            var markup = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "/Home/Download",
                data: { "htmlContent": markup },
                success: function () {
                    window.location = '@Url.Action("Download", "Home")';
                }
            })
        })
    });
</script>
```

**Controller**

```
public IActionResult Download(String htmlContent)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(htmlContent))
        {
            IronPdf.HtmlToPdf Renderer = new IronPdf.HtmlToPdf();
            Renderer.RenderHtmlAsPdf(htmlContent).SaveAs("html-string.pdf");
            return Ok();
        }
        else
        {
            var stream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath, "html-string.pdf"), FileMode.Open);
            return new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/pdf");
        }

    }
```

Comment: I am assuming the line ```var markup = document.documentElement.innerHTML;``` gets all the content in the html body and pass it to the controller?

Comment: Pdf.Core nuget is now deprecated, replaced with IronPdf - which has full .NET Standard, Core and .NEt 5 support in 2021.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/IronPdf/

Answer (score 1):

Our team Chose IronPDF and it worked based on the MVC tutorial posted:
https://ironpdf.com/docs/questions/asp-net-mvc-pdf-binary/

```cs
public FileResult GetHTMLPageAsPDF(long id) {
  //Create a PDF Document
  var PDF = Renderer.RenderHtmlAsPdf("<h1>html as required</h1>");
  //return a pdf document from a view
  var content = PDF.BinaryData;
  Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", content.Length.ToString());
  Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=Document_" + id + ".pdf");
  return File(content, "application/pdf;");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I later went for [pugpdf](https://github.com/pug-pelle-p/pugpdf) because I couldnt afford IronPDF. Its a good package though.
Pugpdf did the job for me

```
  public async Task<IActionResult> Download(String htmlContent)
        {

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(htmlContent))
            {
                var renderer = new HtmlToPdf();

                renderer.PrintOptions.Title = "Statement";

                var pdf = await renderer.RenderHtmlAsPdfAsync(htmlContent);

                pdf.SaveAs(Path.Combine(_webHostEnvironment.ContentRootPath, "html-string.pdf"));

                return Ok();
            }
            else
            {
                var stream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(_webHostEnvironment.ContentRootPath, "html-string.pdf"), FileMode.Open);
                return new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/pdf");
            }

        }
```